# How to run a job on a specific node using the slurm?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, cvx

My original question is how to run the CVX toolbox (with academic license) on the cluster. I could not figure out a direct way of doing that and  I have decided to tackle the problem in a different way.

The CVX license is hardware dependent and each academic license is tied to 4 hardwares. I want to add one of the nodes (maybe two) to the license list. For doing so, I need to run the CVX always on the same hardware or node (I know this might not be an efficient approach). Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 11):

If you are the administrator, you should defined a `feature` associated with the node(s) on which that software is installed (for instance `feature=cvx`, in `slurm.conf`) and ask users to submit jobs with `--constraint=cvx`.

If you are a regular user and cannot change the Slurm configuration, you can specify a specific node with `--nodelist=...`, or, if you need one among several, use `--exclude=...` with the list of all nodes that do not have CVX installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did some research and it seems one can use #SBATCH w <nodename>

Comment: `-w` is the short version of the `--nodelist` option.

Comment: How to exclude/select multiple nodes? like I want to exclude node17 and node06... `--exclude node17 node 06`? or what?